# Several nameref and page margins

Tags: hyperref, line-breaking, urls

I've been struggling with `nameref` for some time now. I am trying to make them respect the available space there is on a line, but I can't seem to find how.

The LaTeX code is the following:

```
\documentclass{report}
%\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[inner=3.5cm,outer=2.5cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,pdftex]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[pdftex]{hyperref}

\hypersetup{
    colorlinks = true
}

\overfullrule=15pt % debug

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter name}

\section{Section name}

\subsection{XML\_DOM\_NodeFirstSonGet}\label{XMLDOMNodeFirstSonGet}
\subsection{XML\_DOM\_NodeSonsCount}\label{XMLDOMNodeSonsCount}
\subsection{XML\_DOM\_NodeSonsGet}\label{XMLDOMNodeSonsGet}
\subsection{XML\_DOM\_NodeSonsNodesCount}\label{XMLDOMNodeSonsNodesCount}
\subsection{XML\_DOM\_NodeSonsNodesCount}\label{XMLDOMNodeSonsNodesGet}

Normal text:\\\newline
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse\

See \nameref{XMLDOMNodeFirstSonGet}, \nameref{XMLDOMNodeSonsCount}, \nameref{XMLDOMNodeSonsGet}, \nameref{XMLDOMNodeSonsNodesCount}, \nameref{XMLDOMNodeSonsNodesGet}.\
See \nameref{XMLDOMNodeFirstSonGet}, \nameref{XMLDOMNodeSonsCount}, \nameref{XMLDOMNodeSonsNodesCount}, \nameref{XMLDOMNodeSonsNodesGet}.\

See \nameref{XMLDOMNodeFirstSonGet}, \nameref{XMLDOMNodeFirstSonGet}, \nameref{XMLDOMNodeFirstSonGet}, \nameref{XMLDOMNodeSonsCount}, \nameref{XMLDOMNodeSonsNodesCount}, \nameref{XMLDOMNodeSonsNodesGet}, \nameref{XMLDOMNodeFirstSonGet}.
\end{document}
```

And the resulting PDF looks like this:

[image]

As you can see, the second and third line containing `\nameref`s are overfull and won't respect the line width as the normal text does.

The result is even worst with `\documentclass{scrreprt}` as they are all overfull and cropped by the page limit:

[image]

As I don't know the length of the string that will be displayed, I can't arbitrarily force a new line.

What also strikes me is that I didn't find any information about this behavior. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Your post was migrated here from another Stack Exchange site. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The paragraph structure for those containing `\nameref` is "bad" since TeX has no way of forcing a line-break within the unknown "words". As a possible correction, and to see how bad it may look if TeX didn't care so much about making things look pretty, add `\sloppypar` (or at least scope it within a group `{`...`}` around the affected paragraphs) before the `\nameref` paragraphs. Alternatives include using `\raggedright` or perhaps a breakable underscore (or combination of either):

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Here's a complete example:

```
\documentclass{report}
%\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[inner=3.5cm,outer=2.5cm,top=1cm,bottom=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\hypersetup{
    colorlinks = true
}

\overfullrule=15pt % debug

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter name}

\section{Section name}

\subsection{XML\textunderscore DOM\textunderscore NodeFirstSonGet}\label{XMLDOMNodeFirstSonGet}
\subsection{XML\textunderscore DOM\textunderscore NodeSonsCount}\label{XMLDOMNodeSonsCount}
\subsection{XML\textunderscore DOM\textunderscore NodeSonsGet}\label{XMLDOMNodeSonsGet}
\subsection{XML\textunderscore DOM\textunderscore NodeSonsNodesCount}\label{XMLDOMNodeSonsNodesCount}
\subsection{XML\textunderscore DOM\textunderscore NodeSonsNodesCount}\label{XMLDOMNodeSonsNodesGet}

Normal text:

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse

Using \verb|\sloppypar|:

{\sloppypar
See \nameref{XMLDOMNodeFirstSonGet}, \nameref{XMLDOMNodeSonsCount}, \nameref{XMLDOMNodeSonsGet}, \nameref{XMLDOMNodeSonsNodesCount}, \nameref{XMLDOMNodeSonsNodesGet}.

See \nameref{XMLDOMNodeFirstSonGet}, \nameref{XMLDOMNodeSonsCount}, \nameref{XMLDOMNodeSonsNodesCount}, \nameref{XMLDOMNodeSonsNodesGet}.

See \nameref{XMLDOMNodeFirstSonGet}, \nameref{XMLDOMNodeFirstSonGet}, \nameref{XMLDOMNodeFirstSonGet}, \nameref{XMLDOMNodeSonsCount}, \nameref{XMLDOMNodeSonsNodesCount}, \nameref{XMLDOMNodeSonsNodesGet}, \nameref{XMLDOMNodeFirstSonGet}.
}

\bigskip

Using \verb|\raggedright|:

{\raggedright
See \nameref{XMLDOMNodeFirstSonGet}, \nameref{XMLDOMNodeSonsCount}, \nameref{XMLDOMNodeSonsGet}, \nameref{XMLDOMNodeSonsNodesCount}, \nameref{XMLDOMNodeSonsNodesGet}.

See \nameref{XMLDOMNodeFirstSonGet}, \nameref{XMLDOMNodeSonsCount}, \nameref{XMLDOMNodeSonsNodesCount}, \nameref{XMLDOMNodeSonsNodesGet}.

See \nameref{XMLDOMNodeFirstSonGet}, \nameref{XMLDOMNodeFirstSonGet}, \nameref{XMLDOMNodeFirstSonGet}, \nameref{XMLDOMNodeSonsCount}, \nameref{XMLDOMNodeSonsNodesCount}, \nameref{XMLDOMNodeSonsNodesGet}, \nameref{XMLDOMNodeFirstSonGet}.
}

\bigskip

Different \verb|\textunderscore|:

{\let\oldtextunderscore\textunderscore%
\renewcommand{\textunderscore}{\oldtextunderscore\hspace{0pt}}%
See \nameref{XMLDOMNodeFirstSonGet}, \nameref{XMLDOMNodeSonsCount}, \nameref{XMLDOMNodeSonsGet}, \nameref{XMLDOMNodeSonsNodesCount}, \nameref{XMLDOMNodeSonsNodesGet}.

See \nameref{XMLDOMNodeFirstSonGet}, \nameref{XMLDOMNodeSonsCount}, \nameref{XMLDOMNodeSonsNodesCount}, \nameref{XMLDOMNodeSonsNodesGet}.

See \nameref{XMLDOMNodeFirstSonGet}, \nameref{XMLDOMNodeFirstSonGet}, \nameref{XMLDOMNodeFirstSonGet}, \nameref{XMLDOMNodeSonsCount}, \nameref{XMLDOMNodeSonsNodesCount}, \nameref{XMLDOMNodeSonsNodesGet}, \nameref{XMLDOMNodeFirstSonGet}.
}

Different \verb|\textunderscore| + \verb|\sloppypar|:

{\let\oldtextunderscore\textunderscore\sloppypar%
\renewcommand{\textunderscore}{\oldtextunderscore\hspace{0pt}}%
See \nameref{XMLDOMNodeFirstSonGet}, \nameref{XMLDOMNodeSonsCount}, \nameref{XMLDOMNodeSonsGet}, \nameref{XMLDOMNodeSonsNodesCount}, \nameref{XMLDOMNodeSonsNodesGet}.

See \nameref{XMLDOMNodeFirstSonGet}, \nameref{XMLDOMNodeSonsCount}, \nameref{XMLDOMNodeSonsNodesCount}, \nameref{XMLDOMNodeSonsNodesGet}.

See \nameref{XMLDOMNodeFirstSonGet}, \nameref{XMLDOMNodeFirstSonGet}, \nameref{XMLDOMNodeFirstSonGet}, \nameref{XMLDOMNodeSonsCount}, \nameref{XMLDOMNodeSonsNodesCount}, \nameref{XMLDOMNodeSonsNodesGet}, \nameref{XMLDOMNodeFirstSonGet}.
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: That did the trick. I'll use the last one, '\textunderscore + \sloppypar'. Thanks a lot for your time Werner.